# How to reduce amount of faces on plane?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have a large flat plane with almost 3k faces but it could be 1 huge face. How can I do it?

[image: Flat plane that could have less faces]

Comment: Just use delete->limited dissolve

Answer (score 2):

give it a decimate modifier and play with the ratio until faces count is very low like 3:

[image]

then apply the modifier and go in edit mode and delete the superfluous edges:

[image]

with "limited dissolve"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1.) Go <kbd>tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode*
2.) Press <kbd>1</kbd> to switch to *Vertex Select* mode
3.) Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all vertices
4.) Then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> all 4 corner vertices to deselect them
5.) Press <kbd>X</kbd> & choose *Dissolve Vertices*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Deselect All in Edit mode. <kbd>⇧ Shift CLICK</kbd> all 4 corner vertices. <kbd>⎈ Ctrl I</kbd> to invert the selection then <kbd>⎈ Ctrl X</kbd> to delete them with limited dissolve.

Comment: why not just X > Limited Dissolve?

Comment: One less action to think about! :^)